# Is it a good practice to double check if the repository exists in the initState of a child widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I am wrapping my MaterialApp with a `RepositoryProvider` and I would like to access it in one of the child widgets. In the child widget's `initState()` I am assigning the repository instance to my local class's property as such:

```
class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
AuthenticationRepository? _authenticationRepository;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    if(RepositoryProvider.of<AuthenticationRepository>(context) != null){  /* at this point dart analyzer 
    is showing the warning: "The operand can't be null, so the condition is always true. 
    Remove the condition." */
     _authenticationRepository = RepositoryProvider.of<AuthenticationRepository>(context); 

    }
  }
}
```

I know that `RepositoryProvider.of<AuthenticationRepository>(context)` will be accessible for sure, as the entire `MaterialApp` widget is wrapped with the RepositoryProvider. However, I just prefer double checking if it's not null. Please let me know if this is a bad practice and should I just ignore the dart analyzer's warning?

Comment: Its useless as the analyzer suggest because you always give generic type to Provider.of<T> if you relly want to be safe then check the variable is null or not inside provider

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that's really really **a bad idea**. If you take a deeper look at `provider of method implementation`, you will see that there is a `ProviderNullException`. It will throw when you don't wrap ancestor widgets by respective Provider. So, it's **unlikely** that it will return `null` value. instead, it'll throw **exception**. If it throws, you catch it.

**A good practice** is just wrap your `RepositoryProvider.of<AuthenticationRepository>(context)` in a `try,catch block`. Call `Provider.of` method in try block and catch `ProviderNullException`. Cheers.

This is the provider's `of` method implementation.

```
static T of<T>(BuildContext context, {bool listen = true}) {
    assert(
      context.owner!.debugBuilding ||
          listen == false ||
          debugIsInInheritedProviderUpdate,
      '''
Tried to listen to a value exposed with provider, from outside of the widget tree.
This is likely caused by an event handler (like a button's onPressed) that called
Provider.of without passing `listen: false`.
To fix, write:
Provider.of<$T>(context, listen: false);
It is unsupported because may pointlessly rebuild the widget associated to the
event handler, when the widget tree doesn't care about the value.
The context used was: $context
''',
    );

    final inheritedElement = _inheritedElementOf<T>(context);

    if (listen) {
      // bind context with the element
      // We have to use this method instead of dependOnInheritedElement, because
      // dependOnInheritedElement does not support relocating using GlobalKey
      // if no provider were found previously.
      context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_InheritedProviderScope<T?>>();
    }

    final value = inheritedElement?.value;

    if (_isSoundMode) {
      if (value is! T) {
        throw ProviderNullException(T, context.widget.runtimeType);
      }
      return value;
    }

    return value as T;
  }
```